# TSQL - How do you find missing values from another table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

**Goal:**

Based on the temp tables below, there are 2 docID's that don't have any records in the #TemplateKey temp table (docID's 12 and 13, neither have keyID 111.) I'm trying to get all DocID's that don't have a keyID in the #TemplateKey temp table.

**Desired Result:**

DocID:

12

13

(These two DocID's don't have TemplateID's 12, 13)

How can I get the desired result please?  I've tried a number of things including the following which doesn't work.

```
SELECT docID FROM #WorkTable WHERE keyID NOT IN (SELECT keyID FROM #TemplateKey)
```

---

I've created temp tables with data to help those that would help me figure this out.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#WorkTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #WorkTable
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TemplateKey') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TemplateKey


CREATE TABLE #WorkTable (
  GroupDocID          int
, KeyId       int  
)

INSERT INTO #WorkTable(
    GroupDocID
    , KeyID
    )

VALUES
( 10    ,111 )
,(10    ,222 )
,(10    ,333 )
,(10    ,444 )
,(11    ,111 )
,(11    ,222 )
,(11    ,333 )
,(11    ,444 )
,(12    ,222 )
,(12    ,333 )
,(12    ,444 )
,(12    ,555 )
,(13    ,222 )
,(13    ,333 )
,(13    ,444 )
,(13    ,555 )

SELECT * FROM #WorkTable 
--===============================================================================
CREATE TABLE #TemplateKey (
  KeyID          int
)

INSERT INTO #TemplateKey(
    KeyID
)
VALUES
 (111)
,(112)
,(113)
,(114)
,(115)
,(116)

SELECT * FROM #TemplateKey AS tk
```

Comment: Why should `21241` appear in  the results? All the rows for that value are in the table `#TemplateKey` too.

Comment: seems like your sample data doesn't match with your desired result.

Comment: @Larnu, 21241 does not contain 1128, or 1129, so it should show up.  I may not be communicating well.

Comment: @JM1 so, how to define the missing TempKey, seems like all you need is to find DocID not contain 1128 or 1129? Otherwise, if you say 21241 doesn't contain 1128 or 1129, then it doesn't contain 1130,1131,1132...either.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this query can work for you

```
select distinct GroupDocID from #WorkTable
except
select distinct GroupDocID
from #WorkTable 
left join #TemplateKey on #WorkTable.KeyId = #TemplateKey.KeyID
where not  #TemplateKey.KeyID is null
```

Comment: Thanks @EmiFala, I changed the question to hopefully make it easier to understand, so I am no longer using some of the columns you referenced.  Thanks for the help though.

Comment: ok, I edited the answer. Check it out now.